# Indexing and Calling Cell information in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Alright so I use excel a lot because of its cross platform functionality and I'm fed up of some of the very long workflows I have to complete for a load of weekly reports I have to do.

I've been experimenting with this for about 2 weeks and I'm not happy with any of it.

I need to input several different reports into a spreadsheet. Except all of the reports the data is in a different order and there is no way to make them all the same format. So what I was hoping to do was to give each product line (theres 170-300 product lines on each report) a numerical value and then have the spreadsheet call the cells from the different pages using its numerical index. Similar to the most basic of tables in C/C++ (the only coding knowledge I have). I have experimented with Vlookup and Address but both cant be used together and address only returns the address of the cell (but there is no way to then get this to read the data out of the cell and then other pieces of information relating to that cell.

If anyone has any ways of helping me out with this then I would be massively appreciative. P.s. To keep this simple all the reports are manually inputted so they all have the same formatting just on different sheets.

Comment: `INDEX MATCH` should do what you are after. Can you post a small sample of data in your question?

Comment: @TimWilkinson ! MY MAN!, Cheers, never even heard of it. Got it working.

Comment: I'll post an example answer for those that come across this question.

Comment: If you are consolidating data from multiple sheets, you should check out Merge query in PowerQuery https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Merge-queries-Power-Query-FD157620-5470-4C0F-B132-7CA2616D17F9. PowerQuery is available for Excel 2010 and later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX MATCH` to match rows and columns,

```
    First   Sec      Thi
A   Apple   Orange   Banana
B   Grape   Peach    Harambe
C   Lime    Steve    Goat

=INDEX(A:D, MATCH("B",A:A, 0), MATCH("Thi",1:1, 0))
```

Will return 'Harambe'.